# How can I move a png from tmp PCLStorage to local non-temporary PCLStorage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using an older version of Xamarin.Forms (3.6) and I'm trying to save a WebView as a PNG so I can view it offline. I found a way to save the image using Forms9Patch (1.3.3).

```
public void saveWebLicense()
{
    var htmlLicenseSource = LicenseSource;
    var fileName = $"{CurrentLicense.customerId}WebViewPNG";
    Forms9Patch.HtmlStringExtensions.ToPng(htmlLicenseSource.Html, fileName, async (string path) =>
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("A PNG of your HTML is here: " + path);

        }
    });
}
```

Which does fine in saving the png to a filename that looks like this.

```
/Users/firstname.lastname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8C7D30F5-F30E-48F6-9584-357193BD5CBB/data/Containers/Data/Application/BE627F14-1EC2-46C8-B015-8F57929111C3/tmp/12345WebViewPNG.png
```

I can navigate to this folder and see the PNG just fine. The issue is it's stored in a tmp folder and as soon as I exit the app it's gone, so I'm unable to load it. I can't change the save location that Forms9Patch gives me, so my thought was to try and move the image to a different local non-temporary folder or copy it. I need something that works for iOS and Android, and I won't be able to upgrade Xamarin.Forms or Forms9Patch at this time, so I can't use any of their new features. I've tried using File.Move but that function isn't even recognized even when adding System and SystemIO.

I'm also open to other suggestions if they work with older versions of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: is your Forms project PCL or .NET Standard?

Comment: Currently it’s PCL. I tried upgrading but ran into a lot of issues.

Comment: my memory is a little fuzzy on this, but in the PCL days I believe that most file access was done via DependencyService and platform specific implementations.

Comment: I'll google some info in that and see what I can find.

Comment: you can use Xamarin.Essentials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?tabs=android  It work with .net standard but not sure about PCL because this working of file system in essentials is been added later after .Net Standard came into picture